# Passing url as parameter to web service method

Tags: url, service, parameters

I'm writing a web service which expects one of the parameters (called "hlink") to be a url.  Before calling the web service I URLEncode the parameter in question ("hlink").  I then call the web service with an hlink parameter value of `'a.apsx?a=1&b=2`. When the request arrives at the web service method I can examine hlink - it has received the url ok, but only as `"a.aspx?a=1"` - i.e. it has lost the `&b=2` part of the parameter.  This seems to be asp.net stripping off the `&b=2` bit - how can I get the whole parm value passed into my web method?

Thanks very much!

Comment: It might be easier if you could provide some sample calling code and also explain how/where you are calling the method (via javascript, compiled code, etc). Also is the webservice written in .NET or are you just using an aspx url as an example of a url that would be passed to the service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you absolutely certain that you are urlencoding the value before placing it in the query string?  The query string parser splits on the '&' sign, which should be %26 after it is url encoded.  If it remains as an '&' character, it will cause the query string parser to b=2 is another name value pair in the outer query string.  I'd take a closer look at what you are sending.

You should see something like this: hlink=a.apsx%3Fa%3D1%26b%3D2